# Web control to view PDF files, videos and power point presentation

Tags: c#, flash, silverlight

We are looking for a web control capable of displaying PDF files, videos and power point presentation. This is part of research school web site, where students can view these files. No download should be permitted. Appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: You can try [infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet/). For PDF files not sure if you can control the save/download behavior of the PDF file.

Comment: Its big! Looking for free/open source

Comment: Try [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/04/6-javascript-jquery-pdf-viewer-plugin.html) for PDF viewer and [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/05/8-html5-jquery-video-player-plugin.html) for video players

Comment: @Nilesh:Thanks for your links. Download option is permitted; we want to block download; any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used PDF.js (https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/pdfjs/) which is very good and download could be prevented